# How to implement like for facebook and share for twitter with custom text in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, twitter, facebook-like

I want to implement like for facebook and share for twitter with custom text. (Means text is already predefined). How can i do that.

I tried these:--

```
gem 'facebook_share'
addthis.com // as their promotion they are adding @addthis which is obvious for using there services but i want to have that.
```

Comment: @AndrewMarshall check edit part..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these two. No need to include any sdk, plugin etc. Nothing. Just copy and paste it on ur view file.

For facebook:--

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=google.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=recommend&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

for twitter:--

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="google.com" data-text="this is the custom text." data-count="horizontal" data-via="MyTwitterAccountUsername">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For twitter:

```
<a href='https://twitter.com/share?url=google.com&text=Signup>Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>
```

For facebook: you can use the feed method API:

```
function streamPublish(name, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){        
            FB.ui({ method : 'feed', 
                    message: userPrompt,
                    link   :  hrefLink,
                    caption:  hrefTitle,
                    picture: 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'
           });

        }
        function publishStream(){
            streamPublish("Stream Publish", "Google", "http://google.com/", "Check it out");
        }
```